# Return results based on total days computed

Tags: postgresql

I'll give a background on how is organized our tables that are involved in the problem I want to solve. We have the following structure in our database:

```
-- In STAFF table we save info about our employees
-- such as their staff_id, name, surname, email, etc

+---------------------------+
|           staff           |
+----------+------+---------+
| staff_id | name | surname |
+----------+------+---------+
|   1234   | Jose |   Ruz   |
|   ....   | .... |   ...   |
+----------+------+---------+


-- In PLAN table we save data that tells at which project is a staff
-- working on in the fortnight, we store the project id (another table
-- but not of interest in this query), the staff associated with the
-- project, hours planned to work and date (fortnight) of this plan

-- In the example below, staff with id 1234 (Jose) must work 88 total
-- hours in the second fortnight of march (2018-3-16 to 2018-3-31) on two
-- projects

+-------------------------------------------+
|                    plan                   |
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+
| project_id | staff_id | hours |    date   |
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+
|    9999    |   1234   |   44  | 2018-3-30 |
|    9998    |   1234   |   44  | 2018-3-30 |
|    ....    |   ....   |   ..  |    ...    |
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+


-- And the last table involved is REPORT_HC, where the staff save information
-- about their work to the projects; they must report (save data in this table)
-- everyday, so, for example:

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                           report_hc                       |
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+
| project_id | staff_id | hours |           date            |
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+
|    9999    |   1234   |   6   | 2018-3-16 14:15:41.487-04 |
|    9998    |   1234   |   2   | 2018-3-16 18:44:34.487-04 |
|    9998    |   1234   |   8   | 2018-3-19 08:11:05.930-04 |
|    ....    |   ....   |  ...  |           .....           |
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+

-- project_id column in report_hc doesn't matter here but I put it
-- to give a better understanding
```

This is the query that I'm trying:

```
-- Generate days workables in the fortnight
WITH days_workables AS (
  SELECT  COUNT(*)  AS total
  FROM  GENERATE_SERIES(timestamp '2018-3-16', timestamp '2018-3-31', interval '1 day') AS days

  -- Get only week days (monday, tuesday, ..., friday)
  WHERE EXTRACT('ISODOW' FROM days) < 6
),

calc AS (
  SELECT  hc.date::date                             AS date_reference,
          SUM(hc.hours)                             AS hours_reported_per_day,
          TO_CHAR(AVG(hc.date::time), 'HH12:MI AM') AS average_time_per_day,

          st.staff_id                   AS staff_id,
          st.surname || ', ' || st.name AS staff_name,

          -- Depending on the hours planned and the available days
          -- to work in the fortnight, each staff have an average of
          -- hours that needs to report every workable day, for example,
          -- if a user has 88 hours planned and there are 11 days workables
          -- he must report 8 hours each day
          --
          -- We use COALESCE to force 0 in SUM instead of possible NULL 
          -- and NULLIF to avoid division by zero 
          (
            SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(pl.hours), 0) AS hours
            FROM  v1.plan AS pl
            WHERE pl.date BETWEEN '2018-3-16' AND '2018-3-31'
              AND pl.staff_id = st.staff_id
          )
          /
          NULLIF((
            SELECT  total
            FROM  days_workables
          ), 0) AS hours_to_report_per_day,

          -- Ok, once we have the hours_to_report_per_day we must
          -- calculate if the user exceeded or reported less hours
          -- than the expressed this day, we calculate it using a
          -- percentage form, so for example, if the user should report
          -- 8 hours but instead he did 5 the percentage will be -37.5
          -- taking 8 hours as a 100%
          ROUND(((
            (SUM(hc.hours) * 100.0)
            /
            NULLIF(((
              SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(pl.hours), 0) AS hours 
              FROM  v1.plan AS pl 
              WHERE pl.date BETWEEN '2018-3-16' AND '2018-3-31' 
                AND pl.staff_id = st.staff_id
            ) / NULLIF((
              SELECT  * 
              FROM  days_workables
            ), 0)), 0)
          ) - 100.0), 2) AS percentage_of_report_achieved
FROM      v1.staff      AS st
LEFT JOIN v1.report_hc  AS hc ON (hc.staff_id = st.staff_id AND hc.date BETWEEN '2018-3-16' AND '2018-3-31')

WHERE st.staff_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT staff_id
  FROM  v1.plan
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-3-16' AND '2018-3-31'
)
GROUP BY  hc.date::date,
          st.staff_id,
          st.surname,
          st.name
)

-- We use non-descriptive alias only to get a 'nicely-view' result
SELECT  date_reference AS a,
        average_time_per_day AS g,
        staff_id AS b,
        staff_name AS c,
        hours_to_report_per_day AS d,
        hours_reported_per_day AS e,
        percentage_of_report_achieved AS f,
        SUM(percentage_of_report_achieved) OVER w AS h
FROM  calc

-- We create a partition to sum at the last each value get from percentage_of_report_achieved
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY staff_id ORDER BY fecha_reporte)
ORDER BY  nombre ASC,
          fecha_reporte ASC
```

This is part of the result I get:

```
     a      |    g     |   b   |                  c                   | d  | e  |   f    |    h    
------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------------+----+----+--------+---------
 2018-03-16 | 07:23 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-19 | 06:22 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-20 | 08:45 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-21 | 07:15 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-22 | 02:51 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-23 | 07:29 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-26 | 11:43 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-27 | 08:45 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  8 |   0.00 |    0.00
 2018-03-28 | 08:40 AM | 12879 | Andrade McCann, Wendy Daniele        |  8 |  5 | -37.50 |  -37.50
 2018-03-16 | 10:26 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   33.33
 2018-03-19 | 08:42 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   66.66
 2018-03-20 | 09:11 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   99.99
 2018-03-23 | 07:14 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  133.32
 2018-03-26 | 11:17 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  166.65
 2018-03-27 | 08:13 AM | 12855 | Aarons Wujcik, Peter Charles         |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  199.98
 2018-03-16 | 09:33 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   33.33
 2018-03-19 | 10:23 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   66.66
 2018-03-20 | 08:21 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   99.99
 2018-03-21 | 08:30 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  133.32
 2018-03-22 | 07:52 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  166.65
 2018-03-23 | 08:17 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  199.98
 2018-03-26 | 11:08 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  233.31
 2018-03-27 | 07:40 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  266.64
 2018-03-28 | 08:31 AM | 13511 | Aray Cappello, Janet Andrea          |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  299.97
            |          | 13536 | Lascody Hernández, Christian Gabriel |  6 |    |        |        
 2018-03-16 | 10:30 AM | 12670 | Astudillo Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   33.33
 2018-03-19 | 08:22 AM | 12670 | Campanaro Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   66.66
 2018-03-20 | 10:02 AM | 12670 | Campanaro Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |   99.99
 2018-03-22 | 10:41 AM | 12670 | Campanaro Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  133.32
 2018-03-26 | 11:17 AM | 12670 | Campanaro Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  8 |  33.33 |  166.65
 2018-03-28 | 09:58 AM | 12670 | Campanaro Méndez, Juan Ernesto       |  6 |  6 |   0.00 |  166.65
```

But there are many problems, take a look at Christian Gabriel, he was planned that fortnight for 6 hours to report every day, but he didn't report anything, I need to be able to see by each day (2018-03-16, 2018-03-19, 2018-03-20, 2018-03-21, etc) 6 hours in the column d (hours_to_report_per_day) and 0 (because he didn't report anything) in the e column (hours_reported_per_day).

In the same manner, Peter Charles, for example, didn't report at 21 and 22 of march, but that result doesn't appear and to see 6 in d column and 0 in e column.

Any help on how can I get the right result? Tell me if you don't understand very well my explanation and I'll do my best to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a deep knowledge using LATERAL but maybe it can be useful but I don't know how to start with it

Comment: you're using timestamps where you should be using dates, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

first create the list of days:

```
WITH days AS (
   SELECT  COUNT(*)  AS total
   FROM  GENERATE_SERIES(date '2018-3-16', date '2018-3-31',  interval '1 day') AS day

-- Get only week days (monday, tuesday, ..., friday)  
    WHERE EXTRACT('ISODOW' FROM day) < 6
),
```

-- then from that days_workables

```
 days_workables AS (
  SELECT  COUNT(*)  AS total FROM days
),
```

-- then finally cross join days

```
calc AS ( 
  SELECT  days.day AS date_reference,
          SUM(hc.hours)                             AS hours_reported_per_day,
          TO_CHAR(AVG(hc.date::time), 'HH12:MI AM') AS average_time_per_day,

          st.staff_id                   AS staff_id,
          st.surname || ', ' || st.name AS staff_name,
--  ...
FROM      v1.staff      AS st
,days 
LEFT JOIN v1.report_hc  AS hc ON (hc.staff_id = st.staff_id AND hc.date BETWEEN '2018-3-16' AND '2018-3-31') 
   and days.day=hc.date::date
),
```

Comment: Your approach is not working, I get the same results even changing the JOIN type.

Comment: I think I got the joins wrong, edited.